# How to redirect focus inside a dialog box in intro.js?

Tags: primefaces, intro.js

I want to redirect at the bottom of the dialog, as i click button at the header of the dialog with name "Click for INSIDE help" as shown in the image.

[Image of the Dialog , you can see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/etubo.png)

Comment: Please read [ask], including [mcve] and http://www.stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info and improve your question... al lot...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I achieve it by creating another dialog as shown below:-

```
  <p:dialog  onHide="javascript:introJs().goToStep(9).start()" widgetVar="helpDummyDialog" closeOnEscape="true" minWidth="900" 
               position="top" >
        <h3>Dummy Dialog</h3>
    </p:dialog>
```

Now on the button "onclik" attribute call another dialog and also use another attribute "oncomplete" to hide it. See the code below:-

```
<p:commandButton  id="helpButton" value="Click For INSIDE Help" onclick="helpDummyDialog.show()"  oncomplete="helpDummyDialog.hide()"></p:commandButton>
```

Comment: How can this be an answer to the question that in itself is totally not clear

Comment: What you are not able to understand?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
var scrollable = $('.ui-dialog .ui-datatable-scrollable-body');
scrollable.scrollTop(scrollable[0].scrollHeight);
```

I tested this in the firebug console:

```
$('.ui-datatable-scrollable-body').scrollTop($('.ui-datatable-scrollable-body')[0].scrollHeight);
```

on the primefaces scroll datatable example here:

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/scroll.xhtml